# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter can't parse a date formatted by itself

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
// 2016-10-10 09:28:45 PDT
String s = zonedDateTime.format(formatter);
// this call fails
ZonedDateTime.parse(s, formatter);
```

What's wrong with the given snippet, shouldn't `formatter.parse(date.format(formatter))` evaluate to the same `date` ?
Exception :

> java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from
>   TemporalAccessor: {MilliOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0, HourOfAmPm=9,
>   MinuteOfHour=28, NanoOfSecond=0,
>   SecondOfMinute=45},ISO,America/Los_Angeles resolved to 2016-10-10 of
>   type java.time.format.Parsed

Comment: Please post the exception and the value of string s to be complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have specified `hh` (lower case h) for the 12 hour clock you have lost the information about whether this is AM / PM so the parse is complaining about that.

Using `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a Z` to include the AM/PM indicator works.

Comment: Or replace "h" by "H". (24-hour-clock)

Answer (score 0):

```
java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-10-10T09:28:45-07:00");

java.time.LocalDate.parse("2016-10-10");
```